# HTML5: Paint multiple canvases on one main canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am looking for a [fast] way to paint images from multiple canvases on the main canvas element.
What is the correct and the fastest way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `drawImage` method of Canvas can accept as first argument a Canvas object. That's the fastest and recommended way.

Here's the extract from [w3.org](http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/#drawing-images-to-the-canvas) :

> // drawing images
>
> void drawImage((HTMLImageElement or
>   **HTMLCanvasElement** or HTMLVideoElement) image, double dx, double dy);
>
> void drawImage((HTMLImageElement or **HTMLCanvasElement** or
>   HTMLVideoElement) image, double dx, double dy, double dw, double dh);
>
> void drawImage((HTMLImageElement or **HTMLCanvasElement** or
>   HTMLVideoElement) image, double sx, double sy, double sw, double sh,
>   double dx, double dy, double dw, double dh);

Note that your canvas elements don't have to be added to your document. I use in memory canvas for all my buffering or sprite objects (`someSprite = document.createElement('canvas');...`).

Answer (score 0):

Dystroy is right, if you want to save the canvas paintings then you can use getCanvasData.